# g++ error : zsh: command not found: subtitle_modifier

Tags: c++, g++, zsh

when i was trying to run my c++ program with these 2 command:

```
g++ subtitle_modifier.cpp -o subtitle_modifier
subtitle_modifier subtitle.srt 3000
```

I got some error:

```
zsh: command not found: subtitle_modifier
```

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: In linux programs are usually not automatically executed from the current directory.

Answer (score 1):

Prefix your binary with `./` such as `./subtitle_modifier` to invoke it from the current directory. Only writing the name assumes it is present in path, which in your case is not true.